# MailMason create plain-text only email template

Tags: postmark

Currently, in mailmason a template with no Layout set, fills both HTML and Text versions of the email template in postmarkapp.

How do I create a template in mailmason so the HTML field in postmark will be empty, and Text set?

It's important for creating small size ticket emails without bloating customer service management software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

https://github.com/wildbit/mailmason/issues/45#issuecomment-577557594

This is a very dirty workaround, I hope to see this feature in the repo